# Scheduling external resources in Dynamics CRM 2011 or 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I would like to be able to schedule external users in Dynamics CRM. I saw in a video at  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwxOhLhfER0 that this is possible, but they didn't show how.

These users will never be logging on to the CRM, but I would still like to schedule them without having to use a Dynamics CRM licence for them.

Anyone have any ideas on how to set these types of users up?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating them and then inactivating the user?

You could also set them up as a resource instead of as a user.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that I could set them up as equipment rather than as a user, but thought that I might be limiting the functionality in some way. Similarly for inactive users - and the process for creating users is fairly onerous these days, unless there's an automated way that I haven't seen yet.

Comment: You can write an application to create users if you know .net.

Comment: For now, I have got around the issue by setting the external users up as equipment - it works well enough, but I would like to be able to use unlicensed users.

Are you saying that we can use .net to create unlicensed, active users? That would be relatively easy for us if it's possible.

Comment: No.  My suggestion was to use inactive users.  Test it first to see if they even can be scheduled and it meets your needs.  Then if it does, worry about automating creation of the users.

Comment: Hi Troy, I had tested that. It doesn't seem to allow me to schedule the inactive users.

As I mentioned I have a solution, but I'm curious as to the scenario you envisage. Using .net to create users shouldn't be a problem for us, but what types of users should we create - just unlicensed ones? Thanks for your answers to date.